# Conserved quantity corresponding to the identity symmetry

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

I am aware of Noether's Theorem which proves that for every differentiable symmetry  of a system, there exists a corresponding conserved quantity, e.g. invariance under rotation implies conservation of angular momentum.

I was wondering what conserved quantity is implied by the trivial symmetry (i.e. the symmetry which does nothing).

Comment: Why does this qualify as symmetry? As far as I remember, Noethers theorem does not apply to **all** symmetries, but only to continuous symmetries. Maybe there are extensions for special cases of discrete symmetries.

Comment: It is the trivial conserved quantity is $A := 0$.

Comment: @Semoi doing nothing is the most continuous thing you can do to something

Comment: @Semoi Yes and no. The Noether theorem does not carry over to that case, namely discrete symmetries do not have an associated conserved current. Nevertheless we have the notion of a charge which acts on operators in the same way as the integral of $J^0$ does. In particular it gives the standard Ward identities.

Comment: @Semoi The trivial symmetry is continuous, in fact differentiable. Unless I am misunderstanding the definition of continuity?

Answer (score 6):

This is a rather academic discussion, but if you plug the trivial transformation into Noether's theorem, the quantity you get is... zero. Which is indeed conserved.